# When using LXML why is the body element not the parent of the table element in this snippet of html

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to process some files that are named xls and can be opened in Excel but they are web archive files There are some nested tables, I want to work first with only the non-nested tables.  I thought I could catch the non-nested tables by looking only for those tables whose parent element had a body tag but for none of my tables is table.get_parent().tag=='body' true.  Even for the table snip below the tag of the parent element of that particular table is a div tag

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv=3DContent-Type content=3D'text/html; charset=utf-8'><script type=3Dtext/javascript src=3DShow.js>/* Do Not Remove This Comment */</script></head>
  <body>
    <table class=3Dreport id=3DID0EI>
      <tr>
        <th>
```

I checked and the body tag is closed as is the table tag.

```
table.getparent()
```

returns

```
     <Element div at 9f05f10>
```

note, I am getting my tables by reading in the document as a string and following these general steps

```
myTree=html.fromstring(someString)
tables=myTree.cssselect('table')


tables=theTree.cssselect('table')
```

Comment: Selecting by CSS might return a different table that is in a div somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xpath to the rescue

```
tree = html.fromstring(someString)
table_tops = set(tree.xpath('//table'))-set(tree.xpath('//table//table'))
```

There is probably some fancy xpath (that some SO smarty will post) to do it but this should be super fast (and easy to read)

**Update**
css version same idea

```
myTree=html.fromstring(someString)
table_tops = set(myTree.cssselect('table'))-set(myTree.cssselect('table table'))
```

Comment: That is slick.  I have never understood xpath but I learned a lot from this example I am presuming that //table is the command to get all tables that are at the root of the document tree?

Comment: `//tree` is anytree anywhere. `//` is anywhere at or below the current node.